# I-Phone: Array doubts

Tags: ios4

i am doing a iphone programming ,i want to know how to split the variables in array .i got a string from web service ,which i have to disply it in table view,but it sucessed.but the problem is the id and username is on same row ,i have to seperate this id and username to different arrays,what can i do?please help me.
thankz in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how is the the returned string separated?
have you looked into using the componentsSeparatedByString method of NSString?